# TRUNC(NVL(COLUMN, '2')) ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a column in table which is `varchar2(3)` style column. This column has some nulls and when I try to run following query it runs for some records but when I scroll to some record I get `ORA-01722: invalid number` error.

Query used:

```
Select TRUNC(NVL(COLUMN, '2'))
from TABLE;
```

Also I ran distinct on column to see what values it has.

```
Select distinct COLUMN
from TABLE;
```

I got following results:

```
1   
2   62
3   90
4   70
5   82
6   71
7   05
8   21
9   81
10  66
11  12
12  95
13  02
14  91
15  92
16  94
17  01
18  65
19  30
20  20
21    
22  50
23  63
24  51
25  64
26  09
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I do this without getting error?

Comment: Are you looking for `trim()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm

Because you want to trunc a string, but `TRUNC` function is for `number` or `date` .

> This function takes as an argument any numeric datatype or any nonnumeric datatype that can be implicitly converted to a numeric datatype

Maybe one of your string value cannot be converted to number

edit : your 21t value is not a number and is not null, you should trim your column

```
SELECT trunc(nvl(trim(column),'2')) 
FROM table;
```

Comment: You are right I needed trim not TRUNC. This clears my confusion.